# Clear value of label

Tags: c#, asp.net, label

I have this code called when a button is pressed:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString() =="ER00 - File Header")
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = 
                   new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["DBcon"]))
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox_ID.Text.ToString()))
            {
                lbl_NoBatchID.Text = "Please enter BatchID!";
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(
                        "Select * from tbl_WinApps_FileHeader Where BatchID =" +
                        TextBox_ID.Text.ToString());

                    sqlCommand.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader read = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

                    GridView1.DataSource = read;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {                           
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how it works: The user inputs a ID, then when the button is pressed, It will display the table in SQL.

If the user did not input anything on the textbox, it prompts "Please enter BatchID!" but after that, it stays in there and it doesn't clear even if I already entered a valid ID. Any idea why that is?

Comment: you may try to set the lbl_NoBatchID.Text ="". see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET pages have something called ViewState that can maintain the state of the controls between requests. You need to clear the DataSource value of the GridView and rebind it.

```
           if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox_ID.Text.ToString()))
            {
                lbl_NoBatchID.Text = "Please enter BatchID!";
                GridView1.DataSource=null;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
```

You also want to clear the error if the lookup was successful:

```
catch(Exception e){
}
lbl_NoBatchID.Text = "";
```

I should also note that your empty `catch()` will swallow any database or lookup errors you might get.

Answer (score 1):

```
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString() =="ER00 - File Header")
    {

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["DBcon"]))
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox_ID.Text.ToString()))
            {
                lbl_NoBatchID.Text = "Please enter BatchID!";

            }
            else
            {
                try
                {

                    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from tbl_WinApps_FileHeader Where BatchID =" + TextBox_ID.Text.ToString());
                    sqlCommand.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader read = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

                        GridView1.DataSource = read;
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                    lbl_NoBatchID.Text = "";
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {                           

                }

            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Else block add this line of code.

```
lbl_NoBatchID.Text = "";
```